# For the parametric equation $ x = 3 \left( \theta - \sin \theta \right) , y = 3 \left( 1 - \cos \theta \right) $ find the derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, parametric

Apologies if this question is a bit too easy for everyone.

**For  the curve defined by the parametric equations $ x = 3 \left( \theta - \sin \theta \right) , y = 3 \left( 1 - \cos \theta \right) $ for $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi $, what is the derivative $  \frac{dy}{dx} $ in terms of $\theta$?**

Seen questions a bit like this before, used the chain rule but not sure how to approach this question. Thanks.

Comment: $$\dfrac{\textrm dy}{\textrm d\theta}=\dfrac{\textrm dy}{\textrm dx}\cdot\dfrac{\textrm dx}{\textrm d\theta}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}=\frac{3 \sin \theta}{3-3\cos \theta}=\frac{\sin \theta}{1-\cos \theta}$$